# how to change material table action fields icon

Tags: reactjs, material-table

```
        actions={[
          {
            icon: 'edit',
            tooltip: 'Edit User',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => alert('You are editing ' + rowData.name)
          },
          {
            icon: 'delete',
            tooltip: 'Delete User',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => confirm('You want to delete ' + rowData.name)
          }
        ]}
```

Comment: Consider adding context and description and format your question properly.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the icon of the action by supplying arbitrary React component as the value for `icon` prop.

> **icon** *string or () => ReactElement* - Icon of button from material icons
>   or custom component

So instead of `edit` or `delete`, add a component of a desired icon. Something like:

```
import { Edit } from '@material-ui/icons'

// ...

{
  icon: () => <Edit />,
  tooltip: 'Edit User',
  onClick: (event, rowData) => alert('You are editing ' + rowData.name)
},

// ...
```

Comment: how do it? give me example please ty

Comment: IT should be something like this icon:() => <Edit /> other wise it will give an error

Comment: Thanks, was a typo basically.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Sample Code like this:

```
<MaterialTable
  // other props
  actions={[
    {
      icon: 'save',
      tooltip: 'Save User',
      onClick: (event, rowData) => {
        // Do save operation
      }
    }
  ]}
/>
```

if you use somethimg like FontawesomeIcon, this sample is good:

```
    <MaterialTable
      // other props 
      actions={[
          {
            icon: () => <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSave} />,
            tooltip: 'Save User',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => {
              // Do save operation
            },
          },
        ]}
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I imported the icon

`import VisibilityIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Visibility';`

and simply passed it like this

```js
actions = {
  [{
    icon: VisibilityIcon,
    tooltip: 'View'
    onClick: (event, rowData) => {
         // Your required onclick functionality
    }
  }]
}
```

Hope this helps... have a nice day